PyShark - Cannot read packets from PCAP file but, PCAP opens fine in Wireshark
I'm trying to read packets from a PCAP file and see the number of packets in it. Later, I would try to perform more operations on each packet. But, the number of packets is always zero. I've tried it with other PCAP file as well. Can someone help me find the problem?
import pyshark
cap = pyshark.FileCapture('./snort.log.1730480966')
print(cap)
print(len(cap))    # Length is always zero for some reason!

I captured this PCAP file using snort IDS. The command I used the capture this file was:
snort -q -b -l /var/log/snort -i eth1 -P 65535 -c /etc/snort/snort.conf &
You can download the file from here.
Although, I can open the PCAP file just fine in WireShark:


I think that you have a syntax error with your input file. Your file is named snort.log.1730480966.pcap, but you didn't include pcap in this statement pyshark.FileCapture('./snort.log.1730480966')
Using the code below I get two packets when I load the packets and obtain their length
import pyshark 

capture = pyshark.FileCapture(input_file='snort.log.1730480966.pcap')
capture.load_packets()
number_of_packets = len(capture)
print(number_of_packets)

P.S. Here is some usage documentation that I wrote for Pyshark. The documentation is a work in progress, because there are lots of way to use the module.
